# Pretty Url Issues in Laravel 5.1

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, url

I want to remove the `index.php` from the url to access the controller action. Therefore I added the following code in my `.htaccess` file in the `public/` folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I would be grateful if anyone reply me and solve this issues.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: My .htaccess code is above for removing index.php after public/index.php in the url and to access the controller action routed in the route file i.e public/index.php/car and my exact requirement is to remove the index.php file form the url of example.com/public/index.php/car

Comment: My issue is above code does not work for removing index.php form the url

Comment: It should be `RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: you mean to say `from the url`. You want to remove index.php as a default file..??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use the default Laravel `.htaccess` file. You should go fine with it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```